# Why do I get a "floating point exception"

Tags: c++, exception, greatest-common-divisor

Not asking for a solution or anything, just a general question. When the getgcd() function gets called, I get a floating point exception. Why is this? I have researched this and cannot find a straight answer. Thanks, also below is the code I am working with.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class D: public E {
private:
        int var2;

public:

        D(int var, int var2) : E(var) {
                var2 = var2;
        }

        void getgcd() {
                int temp;
                int newVar = E::var;
                while (var != 0) {
                        temp = newVar % var2;
                        newVar = var2;
                        var2 = temp;
                }
                cout << "The GCD of " << newVar << " and " << var2 << " is " << var2 << endl;
        }
};

#include <iostream>
#include "A4p2.cpp"
#include "A4p3.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int x, y;
        x = atoi(argv[1]);
        y = atoi(argv[2]);

        if (x < 1 || x > 50) {
                cout << "Input must be between 1-50" << endl;
                exit(0);
        }

        E test(x);
        D test1(x, y);
        test.play();
        test1.getgcd();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "A4p2.cpp"
#include "A4p3.cpp"`Just don't do that!

Comment: Can you include your complete code including your definition of `class E`?

Comment: Yes this is an assignment but the assignment is not over floating point exceptions, I just ran across it an decided to ask. Be a little more leniant

Comment: General answer: most likely, var2 is zero (e.g. divide by zero will trigger a FPE) - why that is, we'd need more info like definition of E, and what A4p[23].cpp hold.

Answer (score 2):

Linux unfortunately maps *integer* division/modulo by zero on `SIGFPE`, which is then naively printed out as "floating point exception". I don't think I ever saw it coming from floating point operations (probably because most FP exceptions have to be turned on explicitly, while integer division by zero always faults on x86).

Most probably you have `var2` equal to zero in

```
temp = newVar % var2;
```

That in turn is probably caused by the fact that, in that loop, you are checking `var` but using/modifying `var2`.

```
while (var != 0) {
        temp = newVar % var2;
        newVar = var2;
        var2 = temp;
}
```

You probably want `while (var2 != 0)`.